# got an error when uploading 14000 rows of csv file

Tags: php, mysql

i have an csv file that has 14000 rows,
im trying to import it on phpmyadmin, I've edited the ff:

```
post_max_size = 750M 
upload_max_filesize = 750M 
max_execution_time = 5000 
max_input_time = 5000 
memory_limit = 1000M

In my.ini (MySQL File)

Under mysqld add: max_allowed_packet = 500M
```

but still when i import it i got an error:
[image: error]:

what should i do?

Comment: What actual MySQL code are you using to import the data?

Comment: ive just done it on import tab of my db i choose my csv file , columns separated with : (;) then i checked (The first line of the file contains the table column names (if this is unchecked, the first line will become part of the data))

Comment: Are you sure you're editing the correct INI file? Did you restart the web server after making those changes? 14000 rows doesn't seem like that many to me. What's the actual filesize of the csv file?

Comment: 1.35 mb ive edited it on xampp/mysql/bin/my.ini

Comment: 1.35 MB is not much at all. Also don't guess. Try `echo php_ini_loaded_file()` to see what it outputs. I meant the PHP ini file, not MySQL. At least on Debian-based distros there are usually 3-4 php.ini files depending on what [server api](http://php.net/php_sapi_name) you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the size of max_allowed_packet to some larger value.